# How to rename all the files from a directory?

Tags: linux, shell, mv

So, i have a given directory, and that directory contains other subdirectories, and every subdirectory can contain a file. I have to change all the files names, so that it will end in ".txt" .

Comment: `find -xtype f -execdir \{} \{}.txt \;` works with GNU find. (Whether or not  `{}.txt` expands is implementation dependent; `-xtype` is a GNUism that allows also renaming symbolic links.)

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this using bash : and go over all your directories with it **

```
for f in *.their_current_end;
do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.their_current_end}.txt"
done
```

another solution would be using : **rename** in Linux

```
rename [OPTIONS] perlexpr files
```

where the rename will rename all the files mentioned like the regex supplied in the perlexpr parameter.

example :

```
rename 's/.html/.php/' \*.html
```

Comment: what about the subdirectories?